# UIView inside UIScrollerView displays with -64 offset

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I'm trying to create a form that will be larger than the screen size and I've decided to use a view inside a scrollerview, then I'm adding the rest of the UI widgets (textfields, buttons, etc.) inside the view.

The view displays and scrolls, but no matter what I try, it displays with a vertical offset of -64 below the navigation controller bar.  Once there the view will happily scroll up down.

I want the view to anchored at the top, just below the navigation bar, and then scroll down.

I am using IB.

Lots of time researching and not many answers that have worked for me.  UIScrollView seems to be like one of those dirty secrets the whole iOS world seems to avoid....

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Check the constraint is not set to something else or reversed

Comment: have you looked into 'Adjust Scroll View Insets' OR have you checked that your navigation controller is transparent.  I think if it's transparent, you may have to set your constraint to make up the difference you are seeing.

Comment: no, my navigation controller is not transparent.  I have a couple of buttons up there for cancelling and/or accepting changes and going back to the main view.

Comment: @Greg - the scrollview constraints are set to 0,0,0,0 to the superview.  I paint the background green and can see that it is hugging the superview.  The constraints for the view inside the scrollview are set to 0,0,0,0 to the parent (that is, the scrollview).

Comment: Is your code building without warnings for the constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this in the storyboard

1- Select the view Controller

2- GO to attributes inspector

3- Uncheck adjust scroll View insets

Comment: Sorry I had been gone for a while working on other things.  Yes, jacob bullock's and user3126427's suggestions solved my situation.  I'm marking user3126427's as the solution since that is what explicitly one must do, step by step.  Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

For your view controller, in the storyboard uncheck the option to extend edges under top bar.